# Google App Engine server not adding CORS headers

Tags: node.js, cors, dialogflow-es

I have an Express server as backend of my Dialogflow chatbot, when I access from the same host, I have no problem requesting the API, but when I access from the Firebase hosting whereI have my web App, I cannot request anything since the CORS headers are not being added, even though I added them. 
 This is the code:

```
// Sends static files  from the public path directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/Public')))

// Set Server Config
app.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParse.json());

app.use(helmet.frameguard());

app.use(function (request, response, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'https://newagent-249c5.web.app/');

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});


// Configure Routes
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// Server index.html page when request to the root is made
app.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
    response.sendFile('./Public/index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log("server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

[This is cross-origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUl8a.png)

[This is the headers when I access from the same origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QkN9.png)

Answer (score 0):

For CORS most important is Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, and that client, who requesting, has host equal to value of this header. You can test things out pretty simple locally, spin up simple express server on, say, port 3000, and serve index.html with another server, express or nginx, on some other port. Then add request in index.html to first server, and try to fix CORS on this simple example.

Comment: Yes, I have done it, and it works, my only doubt is that maybe the Google App engine has some kind of proxy which is removing my Headers and adding their owns, because as you can see in the pictures, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not in the response when is sent cross origin, but it is pressent same origin.

Comment: I worked with Google Cloud and get lots of CORS stuff, not really have them stripped. But yeah, could be that there some configuration, which affecting this, so you better consult with devops.